# HTTP POST request throws FileNotFound exception (but works in Postman)

Tags: java, android, rest, api, httprequest

I'm new to android and about to write my first app communicating with a REST-API. I managed to do a GET request but experienced problems with the POST request. Everything works in Postman - on Android, my AsyncTask throws a FileNotFound exception every time I try to perform the POST request.

Following the API's documentation, I first need to obtain an "accesstoken" with a HTTP GET request (https://vereinsflieger.de/interface/rest/auth/accesstoken) I successfully managed to do that. Using the accesstoken I now want to login with a POST request on https://vereinsflieger.de/interface/rest/auth/signin. For I don't know what reason, my AsyncTask throws a FileNotFound Exception even though the file is there (works without problems in Postman). Is there a problem with the code I'm using or with the API itself?

Thank you in advance!

Here is my attemp:

```
public class HttpPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "POST";
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    public String result;
    public LoginActivity LoginActivity;

    public HttpPostRequest(LoginActivity a) { this.callingActivity = a; }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String stringURL = params[0];
        String logindata = params[1];
        String inputLine;
        try {
            //create URL object
            URL myUrl = new URL(stringURL);
            //create connection
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

            //Set methods and timeouts
            connection.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            **connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(logindata);
            wr.flush();**

            Log.d("RESPONSE", "" + connection.getResponseCode());

            //Create a new InputStreamReader
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            //Create a new buffered reader and String Builder
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            **StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();** //Here is where the exception is thrown
            //Check if the line we are reading is not null
            while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            }
            //Close our InputStream and Buffered reader
            reader.close();
            streamReader.close();
            //Set our result equal to our stringBuilder
            result = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        LoginActivity.onPostFinish(result);

    }
}
```

I expected the return of a String containing JSON data, instead I get the following exception:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://vereinsflieger.de/interface/rest/auth/signin
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
```

Comment: You need to create a new connection for the POST request

Comment: Ok, but what does that mean for my code? In what way do I have to open a new connection?

Comment: You are reusing the connection. Once you use a connection it is gone (you should also close the connection once you have read from it). So, create a new connection for the POST request as you did for the GET request. `URL myUrl2ndConnection = new URL(postURL); HttpsURLConnection secondConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl2ndConnection.openConnection();` and so on...

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get away from the FileNotFound exception :/ I switched to Google Volley library yesterday and now everything works as expected in a very simple way. Thanks for helping me!